# How to model whether discrete count data are statistically-enriched in certain regions for spatial data?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, model, spatial, discrete-data, hierarchical-bayesian

I feel like there is a straightforward way to model this dataset, but I'm a bit stuck.

Let me give you a metaphor for the data first:

Let's say that we are looking at a strip of land of fixed width. There are only two types of regions on this land: either there is sand or there is grass. The length of these patches are not equal: sometimes there are uniform patches of grass which stretch miles, over times there are uniform patches of grass only several feet.

I'm interested in clusters of discrete entities. Let's think of them as trees. We are interested in clusters of trees. (Assume we know how to define these by location---if they're nearby one another within some distance, this is a cluster.) Five or more trees are a group.

The question is this: how statistically enriched are patches of sands with groups of trees?

One must take into account that patches are of different lengths, and that the groups of trees are of different sizes. This is all count data though.

I am able to measure everthing.

```
region     type    clusters    region_length
region1    sand    4           10
region2    grass   4           500
region3    sand    4           25
region4    sand    4           20
```

Further questions: one could include covariates, e.g. certain regions of sand also have snakes, we know rainfall levels, etc. How would I include these?

Actual problem:

I have a genome with certain genes. These genes very in length (naturally). There are effects I am measuring of an enzyme. I want to quantify how enriched these genes are with this effect.

My answer:
So far, I think one could model this as using discrete count regression models, e.g. GLM Poisson/Binomial. However, this shows me a correlation e.g. correlation between sand and cluster size. I would prefer to quantify how statistically enriched sand is with clusters of trees versus grass regions with clusters of trees.

This dataset also could use a hierarchical Bayesian approach possibly...but I don't see how that really helps me.

What would be a good model for this data?