# Discrete weather data causing issue in predicting spatial yield

Tags: predictive-models, spatial, continuous-data, discrete-data

I want to incorporate the weather data into predicting spatial yield.

Major data used:

- 4 years spatial yield data from a 10-ha crop field
- 4 years of daily weather data such as rainfall from a weather station nearby
- Other spatial information such as soil survey.

The aim to predict spatial yield on that field for mapping.

Models considered

- multiple linear regression model
- decision trees
- neural network

I used to treat the rainfall data as continuous variables so I have the columns like this:

`"year"           "yield"         "Rain09.01"      "Rain09.16"      "Rain10.01"      "Rain10.16"      "Rain10.31"      "Rain11.15"      "Rain11.30"     "Rain12.15"      "Rain12.30"      "Rain01.14"      "Rain01.29"      "Rain02.13"      "Rain02.28"      "Rain03.15"     "Rain03.30"      "Rain04.14"      "Rain04.29"     "Rain05.14"      "Rain05.29"      "Temp09.01"      "Temp09.16" "Temp10.01"      "Temp10.16"      "Temp10.31"      "Temp11.15"      "Temp11.30"      "Temp12.15"      "Temp12.30"     "Temp01.14"      "Temp01.29"      "Temp02.13"      "Temp02.28"      "Temp03.15"     "Temp03.30"      "Temp04.14"     "Temp04.29"      "Temp05.14"      "Temp05.29"`

But it seems to affect the prediction because of its discrete nature. What is the best way to combine the weather data in predicting spatial yield? Or should I have them in columns: `"year" "yield" "Rain" "Temp" "fortnights"`?

Similar question here but no answer yet [How to model whether discrete count data are statistically-enriched in certain regions for spatial data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278124/how-to-model-whether-discrete-count-data-are-statistically-enriched-in-certain-r)

Comment: Do you have weather data on the same spatial resolution as yield data? Yield data is yearly? Then 4 years of data is not much ... some ore details please.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen No, weather data is not the same spatial resolution as yield data (which measured at around 3-m intervals). The weather data is collected from one weather station daily. Yes, yield data is collected yearly and 4 years are not enough in the time scale. I'm trying to combine daily weather data with spatially dense yield data over 4 years and build a predictive model (MLR). Not sure the best way to combine them? Should I have them as the variables yield, rainfall01/10, rainfall02/10, rainfall02/10...? Or should I have them as the variables yield, rainfall and date?